# Difference between 'drive for' 'drive in' and 'drive of' where drive is a noun

Tags: prepositions

> drive **for** a better lifestyle

> drive **in** a better lifestyle

> drive **of** a better lifestyle

What is the difference and are they all grammatically correct?

Comment: Can you explain the general concept you are trying to express? I don’t understand what any of the sentences mean. The latter two sentences sound quite weird, while the first sounds slightly more correct (but makes little semantic sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the three phrases, ***"drive for a better lifestyle" is the most commonly used and grammatically correct phrase***, as it correctly uses the preposition "for" to indicate the pursuit of a goal or ambition.

On the other hand, **"drive in a better lifestyle" is not grammatically correct,** as "in" is not the correct preposition to use in this context. If you want to indicate that someone is living a better lifestyle, you might use the preposition "with" instead, such as "living with a better lifestyle."

**"Drive of a better lifestyle" is not a commonly used phrase and it is also not grammatically correct**. If you want to describe a person's strong motivation or ambition towards achieving a better lifestyle, you might use "drive for" or "drive towards" instead.

> **Drive for** usually means the pursuit of a goal or an ambition, with a strong determination or motivation.

**For example:** His drive for success was evident in his tireless work ethic.

> **Drive in** can refer to a physical structure such as a garage or a parking lot where cars are driven and parked.

**For example:** "She pulled her car into the drive-in and parked it there."

> **Drive of** is not a commonly used phrase, but *drive* can be used in combination with other nouns to refer to a particular quality or
> characteristic that motivates or compels someone.

***For example:*** His drive of creativity" or "Her drive of ambition. In this usage, ***drive*** is being used to describe a characteristic or trait rather than a specific action or location.

It's worth noting that "drive" can also be used as a verb, and its meaning can change depending on the context of the sentence.